# Rotation of underlying datasets

Tags: r

### Rotation of points with respect to X and Y Axis

I have 2D dataset which contains 2 columns and 200 rows, Can someone tell me how I can write R code to rotate in XY plane?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that you are trying to rotate the data around the origin.  You can do this simply by multiplying by a [Rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). Here is a simple example.

```
## Generate some test data
set.seed(42)
x = runif(100, -1,1)
y = rnorm(100, 0, 0.2)
XY = data.frame(x,y)

## Rotate data
RotMat = matrix(c(cos(pi/4), -sin(pi/4), sin(pi/4), cos(pi/4)), nrow=2, ncol=2)
Rotated = as.matrix(XY) %*% RotMat

## Confirm through display
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(XY, pch=20, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1), asp=1)
plot(Rotated, pch=20, xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1), asp=1)
```

[image: Rotated data]

Answer (score 0):

Transposing (e.g. `t(df)`)? Considering a minimal example of a data frame of 2 columns and 5 rows:

```
df  = data.frame(y = sample(1:10, 5), x = sample(20:30, 5))

> df
  y  x
1 3 21
2 4 29
3 8 23
4 2 30
5 6 27

t(df)
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
y    3    4    8    2    6
x   21   29   23   30   27
```